# How to get CRC algorithm by result

Tags: protocols, crc

how can I guess CRC algorithm by having some examples(line -> result). It`s 1 byte result. Seems like standard 1 byte CRC is not working here.
Examples are in hex

> 02 08 00 3E 00 00 -> 34
>
> 02 0C 00 3E FF 01 03 9F 1A 00 -> 48

P.S. This is Saturn NFC reader exchange. I can`t find the guide to get algorithm.

Comment: You can try [reveng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/). However it didn't find anything with just those two examples. You need more examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found what I looked for.

Comment: Then you should post an answer to your own question.